# How to validate selected controls

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, validation

Im using bootstrap controls in my application.

I validating my page using **jquery.validate.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js**.

I need to validate only visible controls, but im facing issues there.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="BaseQuesList_4" class="base-ques-list_4">

    <h4 class="blue" style="font-weight: bold;">
        Sample Questionnaire</h4>
    <div class="hr hr-dotted">
    </div>
    <div class="space-12">
    </div>

    <div class="control-group info" ques-id="44" ctrl-type="radio">
        <label class="control-label">
            1
            .
            Physically isolated &amp; access controlled ODC mandated?

        </label>
        <div class="controls">

            <label class="inline">
                <input type="radio" id="rdbBaseAns_38" name="44_question" ques-id="44" value="38" ans-id="38" ans-value="Yes" class="ace valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required" onclick="GetQuesList(this);"><span class="lbl">&nbsp;Yes</span>
            </label>
            &nbsp;

            <label class="inline">
                <input type="radio" id="rdbBaseAns_39" name="44_question" ques-id="44" value="39" ans-id="39" ans-value="No" class="ace valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required" onclick="GetQuesList(this);"><span class="lbl">&nbsp;No</span>
            </label>
            &nbsp;

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Question_44">

        <div base-ques-id="44" id="tblDeptQuesList_45" class="rscDeptQuest38" dept-class="DeptQuesList" style="display: block;">

            <div class="control-group error" rsc-ques-id="45" rsc-ctrl-type="textbox">
                <label class="control-label">
                    <i class="icon-hand-right blue"></i>
                   No. Visitor Policy Defined?

                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                   <input type="text" ques-id="45" number="true" data-val-required="Field is required" data-val="true" name="name_45" id="txtDeptAnswer_45">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>                                                                                                          
    </div>                                                              
    </div>
</div>     

<script type="text/javascript">   
 $(document).ready(function () {
    ConfigureValidator();
});
function ConfigureValidator() {
            var basicDetailValidator = $('#Form1').data('validator');
            var checkatleastOneCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox'][data-val-checkatleastone]");
            checkatleastOneCheckboxes.each(function () {
                var nameAttr = this.name;
                basicDetailValidator.settings.rules[nameAttr].required = true;
                basicDetailValidator.settings.messages[nameAttr].required = $(this).attr("data-val-checkatleastone");
            });
            basicDetailValidator.settings.errorElement = 'span';
            basicDetailValidator.settings.errorClass = 'help-inline';
            basicDetailValidator.settings.highlight = function (e) {
                $(e).closest('.control-group').removeClass('info').addClass('error');
            }
            basicDetailValidator.settings.success = function (e) {
                $(e).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('info');
                $(e).remove();
            }
            basicDetailValidator.settings.errorPlacement = function (error, element) {
                if (element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {
                    var controls = element.closest('.controls');
                    if (controls.find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 1) controls.append(error);
                    else error.insertAfter(element.nextAll('.lbl:eq(0)').eq(0));
                }
                else if (element.is('.select2')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="select2-container"]:eq(0)'));
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            };
        }
 function GetQuesList(ddlAnswer) {
            var QuestionId = $(ddlAnswer).attr('ques-id');
            var AnswerId = $(ddlAnswer).val();
            var className = "rscDeptQuest" + AnswerId;
            $('div.Question_' + QuestionId + ' div[dept-class="DeptQuesList"]').css('display', 'none');
            $('div.tab-content div[class="' + className + '"]').css('display', 'block');
        }
</script>
```

I need to validate **rdbBaseAns_39** control.If the option selectecd for rdbBaseAns_39 is Yes , then i need to **validate txtDeptAnswer_45**. but im validating all the controls all a stretch.

Please help me out.

Comment: Paste some validation code

Comment: I have included    ConfigureValidator(); for validation

Answer (score 0):

Give the separate names `name="44_question"` like this `name="44_question_1"` for radio fields

```
<input type="radio" id="rdbBaseAns_38" name="44_question_1" ques-id="44" value="38" ans-id="38" ans-value="Yes" class="ace valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required" onclick="GetQuesList(this);"><span class="lbl">&nbsp;Yes</span>
<input type="radio" id="rdbBaseAns_39" name="44_question_2" ques-id="44" value="39" ans-id="39" ans-value="No" class="ace valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="Field is required" onclick="GetQuesList(this);"><span class="lbl">&nbsp;No</span>
```